# open an excel file located on the server instead of download it MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, excel, internet-explorer

I'm building a Reporting web application right now with MVC3 and I've come up to a couple problems.

My goal is to have it able to generate and view Crystal Reports, SSRS reports, and Excel documents.

Right now I'm working on the Excel segment and I'm running into more trouble than I thought I would. First off, when I link directly to the file, it either opens inside the browser or it downloads it from the server and if the user makes changes it doesn't actually save it to the true file on the server.

I've tried both linking to the file directly using Razor and a ViewModel with the path to the document as well as directing it to an action that returned a File.

I've also tried linking it to a shortcut to the actual file thinking that if I could open the shortcut it would open the file the way I wanted it to and unfortunately it didn't really open at all.

The users already have access to the files on the server through a network drive, so as of right now they can go into the server, open the excel document, edit and save it no problem. I want to duplicate this effect through a link. The program already has a file browser built, so I can browse between the files and make links to the reports.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you further explain "The users already have access to the files [...] they can go into the server"? - How so? Using a network drive... using ftp... etc?

Comment: Edited to fix it. It's through a Network Drive.

Answer (score 0):

Since they are apparently on a network drive, you can just link to the files directly, relative to the user?

For example: a link to `file://///SERVERNAME/folder/`

I tested it between two computers on the network, and that seems to work. However, you still get a popup asking that you want to do with the file, open or save. (both in firefox and IE)

*Note: Yes, that many slashes seem necessary, lol*

Comment: While this almost works, in IE it opens in the browser, it doesn't open for me at all in Firefox. Chrome is the closest in that it opens outside of the browser, but it is merely downloading a copy of it from the server and then opening it which means they won't be able to do any changes to it.